# How can I fix "change input type" problem in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using from vuetify but i have faced an strange problem! As I change input type with vue, it works in chrome but not in firefox 77.0.1!!

Could u please advise me how can I solve this problem?

This is input html:

```html
    <v-text-field
      ref="password"
      name="pwd"
      autocomplete="new-password"
      v-model="form.password"
      prepend-inner-icon="mdi-lock-outline"
      :append-icon="showPass ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
      :rules="[rules.required, rules.min8]"
      :type="showPass ? 'text' : 'password'"
      label="password"
      outlined
      dense
      required
      @click:append="showPass = !showPass"
    />
```

`showPass` is defind in vue data with false value.

It's result in firefox:

```html
<input name="pwd" autocomplete="new-password" id="input-22" type="'text'">
```

And chrome:

```html
<input name="pwd" autocomplete="new-password" id="input-22" type="password">
```

Appreciate in advance :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce in this [demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/xxZgoRp?editors=1010) with Firefox 77.0.1 on macOS Catalina. Can you update the demo to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Same here. Maybe a cache or extension is causing the problem. Do you still have the problem in an incognito-tab, or after a CTRL+F5 ?